# NTBackup will not recognise LTO Ultrium

Tags: ntbackup

Backup Exec seems to be crashing our server when it runs and I have not had a backup for 2 days so whilst I work on fixing this I would like to use NTBackup just to get something on tape. When I run it there is only the choice of backing up to file ofr 4mm DDS ?

Any ideas? The drive is showing up in device manager.

Many Thanks

Gram

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure you have the correct drivers installed, both for the drive and its controller card. I suspect that may also fix your Backup Exec issue. Do not use Microsoft supplied drivers. Go to the manufacturers' web sites and get the latest (non-beta) versions available.